# Sort calendar of events by date, then time

Tags: php, sorting, date, time

Here is my code. It is a calendar page of events that are sorted by date. I need them to be sorted by date AND time of the day. The Date field and Time field are what I need to format by.

```
<?php do { ?>

    <span class="date"><?php echo date('l, F jS',strtotime($row_rsEvents['date'])); ?><?php if(strtotime($row_rsEvents['date']) != strtotime($row_rsEvents['end_date'])) { ?> - <?php echo date('l, F jS',strtotime($row_rsEvents['end_date'])); ?><?php } ?></span><br>
    <?php if($row_rsEvents['time'] != "") { ?><span class="time"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['time']; ?></span><br><?php } ?>
    <span class="title"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['name']; ?></span><br>
            <span class="location"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['location']; ?></span><br>
    <span class="eventDescription"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['description']; ?></span><br>
    <?php if($row_rsEvents['weblink'] != "") { ?>
        <span class="webAddress"><a href="http://<?php echo $row_rsEvents['weblink']; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['weblink']; ?></a></span><br>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($row_rsEvents['phone'] != "") { ?><span class="webAddress"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['phone']; ?></a></span><br><?php } ?>
<?php if($row_rsEvents['email'] != "") { ?><span class="webAddress"><?php echo $row_rsEvents['email']; ?></a></span><br><?php } ?>

<?php } while ($row_rsEvents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsEvents)); ?>
```

and here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE 
(
    (
        DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d') 
        OR DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
    ) OR (
        DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d') 
        AND DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    )
) AND authorize = 1 
ORDER BY sort_date ASC
```

Comment: You don't show your `SQL` query. Is it possible to use `sort by` to get the order you want directly from the query?

Comment: Here's the query:

SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE ((DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d') OR DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d')) OR (DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= Date_Format(Now(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(sort_date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))) AND authorize = 1
ORDER BY sort_date ASC

Comment: Change your `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY sort_date, time`

Comment: feel free to edit the question and add the query there, so you can nicely format it and make it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks stvcisco...I tried that and it works, somewhat. The time field might be: 7:00 p.m. and that shows up before: 9:30 a.m.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: To help further could you give information about the data types of `date`, `sort_date` and `time` from the table definition?

Comment: Here is the info:
date: date field formatted as text
sort_date: date
time: text

If it makes any difference, our editor enters the TIME in the same manner always. For example: 10:00 a.m.

But sometimes, we have: 10:00 a.m. - 5:00 p.m. 
I only want to sort it by the first time.
Thanks